# issues sorting html elements using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i'm having some issues trying to sort HTML elements with JavaScript...
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="sorting">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
 </div>
```

and javascript code:

```
function spanSort(){
    var div = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("sorting").children);
    div.sort(function(){
        return 1;
    });
}
```

I'm trying to inverse the order of the spans to 5,4,3,2,1... but nothing happens. Can I do so still using the sort method or at least without using any loop (I know it works with for loop)?

Comment: You’re just sorting a copy of a list of elements, you’re not actually modifying the DOM.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the list without regard for the values, or sort based on the values in the elements? Why is your sort function returning `1`? That feels like a hack that assumes a certain sort algorithm.

Comment: my goal is actually sort them based on the values in the elements, but in this case i'm just trying to reverse the order of the elements to understand how to sort them (that's why it's returning 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array#reverse()` then append the sorted elements. A sort outside the dom has no effect in the dom

```js
var sorting = document.getElementById("sorting")

var div = [].slice.call(sorting.children).reverse();
div.forEach((el)=>{
 sorting.appendChild(el);
});
```

```html
<div id="sorting">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
 </div>
```